# why is csrf token changing when I use the web middleware on the api routes?

Tags: ajax, laravel-5.3, csrf, csrf-protection

The `csrf_token()` changes when I use web middleware on the api routes.

**api.php**

```
Route::get('someroute/test', 'somecontroller')->middleware('web');
```

**The controller**

```
return response()->json([
    'sent' => $request->header('token'),
    'actual' => csrf_token()
]);
```

The token header comes from a meta tag that contains the `csrf_token()`

```
<meta id="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

for some reason the token posted on the meta tag is different from the token on the server when I call the `csrf_token()` on the contoller.

Why is this crazy thing happening?

Comment: `web` middleware is applied automatically in Laravel 5.3, you do not need to set it manually.

Comment: @manix nope, actually in the API routes I won't have `csrf_token()` since it belongs to the web middleware. that's why I needed to set it manually.